# Don't show the keyboard when I tapped in TextField

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to Objective C and iOS development in general. I am trying to create an app that would make an `UITextField` to tapped. I want the keyboard not to show when I tap on the `textfield`. then I want many times to tap textfield and don't show the keyboard.

[image: I share the Screenshot]

I Want to try this code but it didn't work.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
       [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: which keyboard you need either it is alphabetic or numeric?

Comment: what do you mean by don't show the system keyboard??? I think its system keyboard

Comment: I want to set the custom keyboard but i don't show the system keyboard when i tapped in `textfield` how can i utilize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can called this functions in delegate methods

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (!textField.inputView) {
        //it hides the keyboard, but cursor will show
        textField.inputView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks For the Reply @Anbu.Karthik. I tried your code and It did work.

Comment: @Ravi -- Ha ha ha, sure bro

Answer (score 0):

You can implement delegate method like,

```
  -(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

      [textField resignFirstResponder];
      return YES;

//Or just return No

 }
```

Make sure that you have confirm protocol `UITextFieldDelegate` and you have set `delegate` property of your `textField` to `self`.

Comment: **Thanks For the Reply** _@Lion_. I tried your code but it did't work you want to answer then check the post in @Anbu.Karthik in this page.

Comment: you're welcome. Then accept his answer if it works. you should accept right answers as per stackoverflow's guidelines.. :)